# List items stacking when made into hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I have 2 groups of code and a rather easy question for most people, nevertheless, a question.

There is this piece of code ready made with working css implemantation:

```
<div class="subTopHolder">
    <ul class="language">
            <li><a href="#" title="Türkçe">TR</a></li>
            <li>EN</li>
        </ul>
```

And it breaks as soon as I turn EN into a hyperlink. Resulting code:

```
<div class="subTopHolder">
    <ul class="language">
            <li><a href="#" title="Türkçe">TR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="English">EN</a></li>
        </ul>
```

In this case, rather than standing side by side with a margin, they are stacked vertically.

Accompanying css code is:

```
div.subTopHolder
{
    width:1002px;
    height:201px;
    margin:auto auto;
    padding:0 12px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(../images/bck-bannerHolder.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

ul.language
{
    float:right;
    clear:left;
    padding:2px 0;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    cursor:default;

}
ul.language li
{
    display:inline;
    background:#f8c180;
    padding:2px 4px;
    font-size:10px;
    cursor:default;
    text-shadow:0 1px white;
    border-radius:2px;
}
ul.language li a
{
    font-size:10px;
    display:block-inline;
    background:#fff;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:-2px -4px;
    padding:2px 4px;
    border-radius:2px;


     transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
}
ul.language li a:hover
{
    box-shadow:1px 1px 8px 0px black;
```

Comment: check for html syntax error here : <a href "#" tile "English">

Comment: @Mouloud sorry, mistyped it here. problem persists

Comment: In `ul.language li a` you have `display:block-inline`. That's **not** a valid statement. You probably meant `block` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set ul.language li to display : inline-block or float: left

```
ul.language li
{
// with ie hack
    display:inline;
    float : left;
    zoom : 1;
}

or

ul.language li
{
    *display : inline;
    zoom     : 1;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things wrong here:

1. First, your html syntax is broken. The correctly formed link should be:

   ```
   <a href="#" title="English">EN</a>
   ```
2. You've applied the wrong style to `ul.language li`. Instead of `display: inline;` give it `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Does work nicely too, will give an upvote once I have sufficient rep:)

Comment: @whotheman, it sure took a while, but you have the sufficient rep now!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
<a href="#" title="English">English</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, mistyped while copying. Not the case in actual web page